# JavaScript simple calculation

Tags: javascript, math, division, multiplication

I'm pretty sure I'm being stupid but why isn't this working!?

```
form.find( '.per_time' ).on( 'change', function() {
            var price = parseInt( form.find( '.section-price' ).attr('data-price'), 10 ) ;
            var multiplier = parseInt( $( this ).val(), 10 );
            var newprice = (price / 7) * multiplier;
            form.find( '.section-price .price' ).html( newprice )
        })
```

It's this line I'm concerned about:

```
var newprice = (price / 7) * multiplier;
```

The calculation is not dividing by 7, it only calculates `price * multiplier`?

This code also seems to be dictating what happens but I'm pretty sure it's jsut a shorter version of the above.

`n.find(".per_time").on("change",function(){var t=parseInt(n.find(".section-price").attr("data-price"),10),r=parseInt(e(this).val(),10),i=(t/7)*r;n.find(".section-price .price").html(i)})`

Thanks for all your help in advance. Here is an example of the input.

`(595 / 7) * 10`

Comment: Java is not Javascript, please !

Comment: *It just wwill not divide by 7!* What does that mean ?

Comment: What do you mean? The result is not correct or an error is thrown?

Comment: Basically the calculation seems to ignore the '/ 7'... For example: 595 / 7 * 10 = 5950. It should be: 595 / 7 * 10 = 850

Comment: Did you try to `alert(price)` and `alert(multiplier)` before `var newprice = price / 7 * multiplier;`, and then `alert(newprice)` ?

Comment: did you try to `var newprice = (price / 7) * multiplier;`

Comment: and you're missing a `;` on the line before it

Comment: Tried it in brackets and corrected the semi-colon. No syntax errors come up. For some reason, this code also seems to be affecting the end result similarly. I think it's just the same as the original code but shorter. `n.find(".per_time").on("change",function(){var t=parseInt(n.find(".section-price").attr("data-price"),10),r=parseInt(e(this).val(),10),i=(t/7)*r;n.find(".section-price .price").html(i)})`

Comment: @Joesruddock You should update your question.

Comment: Updated, Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Tried adding the alerts in, not quite sure what I'm supposed to be looking for though. Nothing seems to have changed so I assume its alright.

Comment: Could you provide the problem in a [Short, self contained, runnable](http://sscce.org/) form? Right now, we can't be sure what other js libraries you're using (jquery maybe? What's this `attr` thing?), or what your html looks like (what's `form`? `section-price`?). If you could reproduce the problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that would be helpful :-)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070939/javascript-division-and-multiplication