# Javascript Division and Multiplication

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure I'm being stupid but why isn't this working!?

```
form.find( '.per_time' ).on( 'change', function() {
            var price = parseInt( form.find( '.section-price' ).attr('data-price'), 10 ) ;
            var multiplier = parseInt( $( this ).val(), 10 );
            var newprice = (price / 7) * multiplier;
            form.find( '.section-price .price' ).html( newprice )
        })
```

It's this line I'm concerned about:

```
var newprice = (price / 7) * multiplier;
```

The calculation is not dividing by 7, it only calculates `price * multiplier`?

This code also seems to be dictating what happens but I'm pretty sure it's jsut a shorter version of the above.

`n.find(".per_time").on("change",function(){var t=parseInt(n.find(".section-price").attr("data-price"),10),r=parseInt(e(this).val(),10),i=(t/7)*r;n.find(".section-price .price").html(i)})`

Thanks for all your help in advance. Here is an example of the input.

`(595 / 7) * 10`

Comment: Your title is misleading.

Comment: can you show us some sample input and output?

Comment: `(595 / 7) * 10`. It should equal 850 but it seems to skip the `/ 7` to equal 5950.

Comment: @Joesruddock: Please [edit your former question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17070186/edit) instead of re-posting a new version of it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a first time user of this site. Still getting used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newprice = price * multiplier / 7.0;
```

Assuming that you are not receiving `parseInt(0.XXXX)`.

Comment: No Luck, unfortunately still no change :(

Comment: What are the vars values?